# Color all text bewteen double quotes in various cases

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to color all text between double quotes but there are cases where it doesn't apply correctly due to br problems.

I first tried this

```js
const regex = /[\"“”]([^\"“]+?)[\"”“]/g;
const colorElement = (x) => {
    x.innerHTML = x.innerHTML.replace(
        regex,
        `"<span style='color: red'>$1</span>"`
    );
};
(col = (parent) => {
    if (parent.nodeName === "SCRIPT") return;
    const childsWith = [...parent.children].filter((ch) =>
        /[\"“”]/.exec(ch.innerText)
    );
    if (!childsWith.length) colorElement(parent);
    else childsWith.forEach((ch) => col(ch));
})(document.querySelector("chapter"));
```

but if the text is not formatted properly this happens:
[image: a missing " messes up the logic]

so to fix it i tried this:

```js
const regex = /[\"“”]([^\"“]+?)[\"”“]/g;
const colorElement = (x) => {
  const ps = x.innerHTML.split(/<br\/?>/g).map(p => p.replace(regex, `"<span style='color: red'>$1</span>"`))
  x.innerHTML = ps.join("<br/>");
};
(col = (parent) => {
  if (parent.nodeName === "SCRIPT") return;
  const childsWith = [...parent.children].filter((ch) =>
    /[\"“”]/.exec(ch.innerText)
  );
  console.log(parent.innerHTML);
  if (!childsWith.length) colorElement(parent);
  else childsWith.forEach((ch) => col(ch));
})(document.querySelector("chapter"));
```

but it doesn't color in this case:
[image: paragraph doesn't end with a "]

In the first solution this text gets colored. It either one or the other solution. I can't think of a way to include both.

Comment: There is no closing quotation mark after `I would visit at will...`. So one way to interpret the result is that `"It's okay"` closes the red text, writes `It's okay` in white, then starts a new red text, which is then closed by the `"` at the beginning of `"Then let's go"`, and so on. You should look at the resulting HTML in the browser. Then having mixed straight and and curved quotation marks probably doesn't help either.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you don't take multilines (flag s) into account.

I'm not sure what characters you want to look for (""/“”).

Look at this approach. The first `for`  loop looks for `"..."` and the second for `“...”`

```js
var el = document.querySelector('div');

for (let i of el.innerHTML.matchAll(/"(.+?)"/gs) || []) {
  el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.replace(i[0], `<span>${i[1]}</span>`);
}
  
for (let i of el.innerHTML.matchAll(/“(.+?)”/gs) || []) {
  el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.replace(i[0], `<span>${i[1]}</span>`);
}
```

```css
span {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
"a b 
c" <br>
"d e f" <br>
“g h i” <br>
“j k l
m n o”
</div>
```